# changing position windowing result

Tags: python, pandas, windowing

The following is the normal result of a rolling window sum:

```
s = pd.Series(range(5))

s.rolling(window=2).sum()

Out[2]: 
0    NaN
1    1.0
2    3.0
3    5.0
4    7.0
dtype: float64
```

I, however, would like it to be

```
Out[2]: 
0    1.0
1    3.0
2    5.0
3    7.0
4    NaN
dtype: float64
```

How can this be achieved with a rolling window?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `s.rolling(window=2).sum().shift(-1)`?

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know the shift function

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let us make it with `shift`

```
window = 2
s.rolling(window = window).sum().shift(-window+1)
Out[270]: 
0    1.0
1    3.0
2    5.0
3    7.0
4    NaN
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know the shift function